# Programmatically offset symbols and polygons using mapbox gl js

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

How do i offset my overlapping symbol layers and polygons placed at same coordinates and same style, one beside another any help would be appriciated.
[you can see lines with offset one beside another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIG8B.png)

[here is the line offset code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi4mF.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can offset symbol layers with `text-offset` or `icon-offset`.

If you're drawing a polygon with a `line` layer, you can use `line-offset` as you have used. If it's a fill, I'm not sure what you want to happen. There's no obvious meaning of a fill "offset".

Comment: Thank you, for suggestive reply, i have tried icon-offset but didn't work